# Remove parallax effect on Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, parallax

I'm trying to remove the parallax effect from a slider on a Wordpress theme but not having much luck, can anyone suggest the changes I need to make to the following code to remove the parallax? Thanks for the help!

```
add_shortcode( 'full_screen_slider', 'bravo_full_screen_slider' );
function bravo_full_screen_slider( $atts, $content ){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'slider_categories'=>'',
        'padding_top'=>'160', 
        'padding_bottom'=>'160',   



),$atts));
$output= "";
if(empty($slider_categories))
    $tax_query = '';
else
    $tax_query = array( array('taxonomy' => 'slider_categories',  'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => explode(',', $slider_categories), 'operator' => 'IN')  );
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'slider',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$flex_slides = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $flex_slides->have_posts() ) :$flex_slides->the_post();
    if (has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID()) ) {
        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
        $attachment_info=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id,'full');
        $attachment_url = $attachment_info[0];
    }
    $temp_array ='<div class="slidecontent">'.apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content(get_the_ID())).'</div>';
    if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'bravo-more-link',true)) {
        $temp_array.='<a class="uppercase read-more-btn" href="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'bravo-more-link',true).'">'.__('Continue Reading','bravo').'</a>';
    }
    if(empty($attachment_url))
        $attachment_url = '';
    $output .= '<div class="slider parallax"><div class="background-animate" style="background: url('.$attachment_url.') 50% 0 no-repeat scroll;"></div><div class="content-area orbit-caption">'.$temp_array.'</div></div>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
return '<div class="full-screen-slider-wrap"><div class="full-width-slider">'.$output.'</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'full_screen_slider_module', 'bravo_full_screen_slider_module' );
function bravo_full_screen_slider_module( $atts, $content ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('slider_categories'=>'', 'padding_top'=>'160', 'padding_bottom'=>'160',),$atts));
    return '<section class="section full-screen-slider no-parallax">'.do_shortcode('[full_screen_slider slider_categories="'.$slider_categories.'" padding_top="'.$padding_top.'" padding_bottom="'.$padding_bottom.'"]').'</section>';
}
```

Comment: you may want to post css and any js related to this slider. php won't be your culprit

Comment: Although, if there is js involved, it might be depending on that parallax class. You might try just removing that. Could also break the whole thing though